# How can I access a string array from one class to another in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to access a string array from one class to another but I have no idea how. I have tried to use `BuilderPages_AutoGenerate reference = new BuilderPages_AutoGenerate();` but I can't access the variables using the `reference` that I make with that line. I've also tried to make each of the arrays public but that is not allowed. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class BuilderPages_AutoGenerate : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        string[] nameHolder = new string[6];
        string[] typeHolder = new string[6];
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

        string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = null;
        conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
        conn.Open();
        DataTable schema = null;
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(connection))
        {
            using (var schemaCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TestTable;", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (var reader = schemaCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly))
                {
                    schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (DataRow col in schema.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ColumnName={0}", col.Field<String>("ColumnName"));
            nameHolder[i] = col.Field<string>("ColumnName");
            typeHolder[i] = col.Field<Type>("DataType").ToString();
            i++;
        }
        /* Testing if the name holder is getting the names of the columns in the given table */
        test.Text = nameHolder[0];
        test2.Text = nameHolder[1];
        test3.Text = nameHolder[2];
        test4.Text = nameHolder[3];
        test5.Text = nameHolder[4];
        test6.Text = nameHolder[5];

        /* Testing to see if the type holders is getting the type of the columns */
        type.Text = typeHolder[0];
        type2.Text = typeHolder[1];
        type3.Text = typeHolder[2];
        type4.Text = typeHolder[3];
        type5.Text = typeHolder[4];
        type6.Text = typeHolder[5];
    }
    public class testing
    {
        //I want to use nameHolder and typeHolder here!!
    }
}
```

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: You can create a singleton in the BuilderPages_AutoGenerate class which would then have properties for both nameHolder and typeHolder members.

Comment: Hi Andy, it looks you don't understand the concept of classes and scope. Because even though you get your refence to work, it will still be emptyh. I suggest you start with a book about how to program: http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Programming-For-Absolute-Beginner/dp/1931841160

Comment: what do you need to do this for?  what is your real requirement?

Comment: A static singleton is not right since multiple classes will be created when serving different requests. You better off by creating that class when you need it and pass it in the parameters you need.

Comment: @sam Thank you I'll actually be taking a c# class soon!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your other method should accept the data that it needs as parameters, it shouldn't be reaching into the page class directly to access the data.

```
public class testing 
{
    public static void Foo(string[] nameHolder)
    {
         //do stuff with nameHolder
    }
}
```

Or, if appropriate, accept the values in the constructor and store it as an instance field.

When the `BuilderPages_AutoGenerate` either creates an instance of `testing` or calls an appropriate method it can pass whatever it needs.

Comment: Thank you this is what I was trying to do!

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of your `testing` class, have it accept two parameters, one for `_names` and other for `_types`, like this:

```
public class testing
{
    private string[] names;
    private string[] types;

    public testing(string[] _names, string[] _types)
    {
        names = _names;
        types = _types;
    }

    // Add methods here that do something with names and types arrays
}
```

Comment: What is the need for making the string arrays public properties?

Comment: Good point, not needed, my mind started on one track and switched mid answer. Updated and removed. Good catch.